# I am here to ask on how can I store the calculation history of my calculator in c++

Tags: c++, calculator

I am new to the coding community and I am here to ask on how can I store the calculations that have been done in my calculator. I am currently new in this space and I am currently looking for answers T-T.
my code goes like this thank you everyone! T-T pls be gentle on me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int calculator();
void history();
void choice();

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tWhat do you want to do?\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t[1] Standard calculator\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t[2] History\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t[3] Exit\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\tChoice: ";
    cin >> x;

    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        calculator();
        break;
    case 2:
        history();
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "\n\n\nThank you for using my calculator!";
        exit(4);
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Enter a correct choice";
        main();
    }
}

int calculator()
{
    double x, y;
    float sum = 0.0, dif = 0.0, prod = 1.0, quo = 1.0;
    int i;

    char op, back;
    do {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "\t\t#CALCULATOR#" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Calculate 2 numbers: (example 1 + 1 or 2 * 2)\n";
        cin >> x >> op >> y;

        switch (op) {

        case '+':
            sum = x + y;
            cout << "The sum of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << sum;
            break;

        case '-':
            dif = x - y;
            cout << "The difference of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << dif;
            break;

        case '*':
            prod = x * y;
            cout << "The product of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << prod;
            break;

        case '/':
            if (y == 0)
                cout << "Undefined";
            else
                quo = x / y;
            cout << "The quotient of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << quo;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid operator";
            break;
        }

        cout << "\nContinue[Y/N]: ";
        cin >> back;
        cout << endl << endl;
        if (back != 'Y' && back != 'y' && back != 'N' && back != 'n')
        {
            cout << "Please enter a correct choice" << endl;
            choice();
        }
        else if (back == 'N' || back == 'n')
        {
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            main();
        }
    } while (back == 'y' || back == 'Y');

    cout << "Thank you";
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

void choice()
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        cout << "Do you want to continue? [Y/y or N/n]" << endl;
        cin >> c;

        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            calculator();
        else if (c == 'N' || c == 'n')
        {
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
        else
            cout << "Please enter a correct choice\n";

        choice();


    } while (c != 'y' || c != 'Y' || c != 'N' || c != 'n');
    cout << "Enter a correct choice";
}


void history()
{
    cout << "I still dont know how T - T";
}
```

I wanted to store the past calculations using arrays but i dont know how to actually put it in my code T-T pls help

Comment: This task will be much easier if you use a vector instead of an array, but I know from experience that people are taught C++ very badly, and they are told to use arrays even though there really is little use for them in C++.

Comment: BTW calling `main` like you do in the default case is not legal C++. It will also limit your options as you develop the code. Instead you should write a loop, a `do { ... } while (...);` loop would be the natural choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `#include <vector>` and make a `history` [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), that holds strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> history;
```

When you do the calculcation, don't output to `cout`, but to a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) first (located in `<sstream>`):

```
std::ostringstream caclulation_stream;
switch (op) {
case '+':
    sum = x + y;
    caclulation_stream << "The sum of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << sum;
    break;

case '-':
    dif = x - y;
    caclulation_stream << "The difference of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << dif;
    break;

case '*':
    prod = x * y;
    caclulation_stream << "The product of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << prod;
    break;

case '/':
    if (y == 0)
        caclulation_stream << "Undefined";
    else
        quo = x / y;
    caclulation_stream << "The quotient of " << x << " and " << y << " is " << quo;
    break;

default:
    caclulation_stream << "Invalid operator";
    break;
}
```

this way, you can save the string to `history`. `push_back()` adds the string to the vector. Don't forget to also print out the string, so it's still displayed in the console.

```
auto calculation_string = caclulation_stream.str();
history.push_back(calculation_string);

std::cout << calculation_string;
```

---

to display the history, you can loop over the vector and print out the elements:

```
void show_history()
{
    for (const auto& entry : history) {
        std::cout << entry << '\n';
    }
}
```

this should give you the basic ideas on how to implement this.

---

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you shouldn't be `using namespace std;`.

Comment: This (or something like it) is the right answer, but I fear it will be unacceptable to the OP. If the OP thinks this is complex, then unfortunately they are going to find the alternatives are worse.

Comment: Hello!! i just want to ask i am currently trying on understanding the answer to my question which is I am really enthusiastic learning about, I am just wondering if where should I put it? and what declaration should I use? I get the concept of it, it is just that I am new to this, idk what declaration should i use for history and calculation_string, i tried using it but the compiler says "calculation_string does not name a type. I am sorry T^T if im asking too many questions.

Comment: You are calling `main()` over and over, so right now you have to put in at global scope (which is bad). You shouldn't follow these bad practices, [here is a list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn the basics. For you to understand the vector, declare `std::vector<std::string> history;` at global scope and you can use it in all functions. if you are still struggling, take a look at the [code, here](https://godbolt.org/z/cr6Y5nYdz). But you should try to figure it out for yourself, first.

Comment: The same problem persists T - T, i included vector and sstream added   std::vector<std::string>history;
std::string calculation_string;
but it still says calculation_string does not name a type T^T

Comment: `std::string calculation_string = caclulation_stream.str();` does not compile?

Comment: it does not unfortunately, i get [Error] 'calculation string' does not name a type even though i already declared std::string calculation_string;

Comment: please compare your code to the code I linked in the first comment, the error should reveal itself.